# On what site can I ask how TAP (e.g. Presto) cards work?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am interested in learning how TAP (e.g. Presto) cards work. It's funny how -

**There is no bar-code, no magstripes (black stripe) and no chip visible on the card, yet it has the same functions as a credit card.**

You reload money on it online and it stores its own information.

I can't find any information on ISO/IEC 7811 on how it is stored.

---

*I want to ask this question on Stack Overflow:*

How is the information stored? How is the card scanned?

Comment: Nope, not suitable for Stack Overflow as it isn't a software question. The electrical engineering site may be suitable, but check their FAQ first.

Comment: I need to set a bounty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid your question may not be on topic for *any* currently existing Stack Exchange site.

Out of the [available choices](https://stackexchange.com/sites), Oded's suggestion of [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) does seem closest, but I don't really see your question falling under any of the topics listed in [their FAQ](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> - a specific electronics design problem
> - the theory and simulation of electromagnetic forces
> - a communication scheme
> - the writing of firmware for bare-metal or RTOS applications

That said, they do have [a somewhat similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/86895/how-electronic-price-tag-works) with seven upvotes, so maybe yours might be OK too.

That said, it's pretty easy to find the basic answer to your question just by [Googling for it](//www.google.com/search?q=tap+presto+card).  The first result I get is the [Wikipedia article](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presto_card), which says (**emphasis** mine):

> "The Presto card, which is the size of a gift or debit card, will use “stored-value” in the form of a common electronic purse (e-Purse) as the medium for all fare payment transactions in addition to cash. Electronic readers will scan the customer’s Presto card (which **contains a passive [RFID](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFID) chip** within the card) as they board their public transit vehicle or enter a station calculating the correct fare and deducting it from their card balance - all within one-third of a second."

(BTW, that text looks like it's been copied straight out of advertising copy for the system.  It seems to have been introduced in [this edit](//en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Presto_card&diff=291673146&oldid=291014253) back in 2009 by a user named "PRESTO card".  Still, it's nowhere near the worst case of self-promotion I've seen on Wikipedia, and at least it does provide useful information.)